# Do we need a tag to comprise questions about predatory, shady, scam and fake publishers?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of now, searching for questions containing the following words mainly used in the context of disreputable publishers yields the following number of results:

- [fake](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=fake+is%3Aquestion): 23 results
- [predatory](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=predatory+is%3Aquestion): 13 results
- [scam](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=scam+is%3Aquestion): 8 results
- [shady](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=shady+is%3Aquestion): 5 results

Now, not all of these questions are actually about disreputable publishers and the search results are not disjunct, but I consider it safe to assume that there are more than 20 questions about this subject without counting them.

There is not one keyword shared amongst all questions about this subject – some examples lacking the respective keywords:
[predatory](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/25916/7734),
[scam](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17379/7734),
[fake](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23332/7734),
[shady](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/26455/7734).
Therefore it is difficult to access all our information about this subject and one might easily miss something.

I therefore suggest that we create a tag for such questions.

---

Should we agree on this: What should this tag be called?

Comment: Please post your suggested tag as an answer, so that people can vote on the question (indicating agreement or disagreement with the need for the tag) and the answer (approval or disapproval for your proposed tag name) separately.

Comment: As there seems to be no big opposition, I added the tag to the first two questions (as soon as the edits are approved). To avoid massive bumping to the front page, I will apply this tag slowly. See also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237535/255554).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest [disreputable-publishers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disreputable-publishers) as name, which has the advantage of comprising all *predatory, scam, fake, shady.* (Not every shady or predatory publisher is a total fake or scam and fake and scam publishers are more than just shady.)

On the other hand, it has the disadvantage of not being frequently used in this context.

Comment: I assume this is also meant to include fake conferences?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: As long as they come together with publications (as it is the default in, e.g., computer science, AFAIK) or hosted by a disreputable publisher: Definetely. I would not have a problem with including other cases (if there are any) under this tag, but somebody else might have. After all, there are a lot of parallels to expect.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: To add to this: In my research for questions for this tag, I have not found any question about a fake conference (or similar) that was neither hosted by a dubious publisher nor connected with a publication.

Answer (score 6):

The [current accepted answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1150/820) strikes a nice middle ground with [disreputable-publishers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disreputable-publishers), but it has the disadvantage that few people posting questions to which the tag will apply will search for such a tag. I propose setting up [synonyms](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) for this tag, along the lines of [fake-journal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-journal),[fake-conference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-conference),[predatory-publisher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/predatory-publisher).

These will be activated when users start typing "fake..." or "predatory..." in the tag selection box, and will guide them to the appropriate tag. For example, typing "pay" currently guides users to [the accepted synonym](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/salary/synonyms), [salary](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary):

[image]

These synonyms [can be set up by popular vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work), but the easiest and cleanest way to get them going (and in particular to avoid questions getting tagged with the subsidiary tags, which changes the behaviour ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnPx3.png)) is via moderator action - if this is OK by the community, of course.

Answer (score -4):

I might recommend [disreputable-actions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disreputable-actions) or [disreputable-practices](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disreputable-practices), as I would think that questions about degree mills and other shady actions could fit into the same category.

Comment: Seems like that would overlap a little too much with "ethics"...

Comment: Also, I would expect questions under *disreputable actions* or *practices* about such actions being commited by the asker or fellow academics. Relatedly, this would include such topics as cheating and plagiarism and make the new tag too broad.

Comment: I should have written that a little more clearly. I still think diploma mills are not that different from predatory publishers—maybe [tag:disreputable-companies] fits the bill?

Comment: We appear to have [two](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23406/11365) [questions](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8681/11365) about diploma mills. I'm not sure need to include them in this tag, if doing so will make it less obvious what the tag is about.

Comment: If you want to bundle disreputable publishers and diploma mills together, how about `not-worth-the-paper` ?